# Is there an rsync equivlent of .gitignore?

Tags: rsync

I have a file that should never be synced in a directory that will be rsynced often. Rather than relying on `--exclude` (and my ability to remember to use it), can I tell rsync to ignore the file in a config file, similar to how `.gitignore` works in Git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the filename extension you want to ignore into `~/.cvsignore`
or into a `.cvsignore` in the same directory as the file.

Put the following alias into your login environment

```
alias rsync='rsync --cvs-exclude'
```

Comment: This is perfect! And documented in the manual for a more precise explanation of how it works (it excludes by default some files and folders, then those referenced in $HOME/.cvsignore, if existing, then looks up the .cvsignore files in the directories you are trying to sync.

Answer (score 1):

alias rsync='rsync --exclude=._-"Your File Name Here"'

To use the .exclusionfiles, i believe you would have to tell rsync each time to use it unless there is ~/.rsync.config file similar to ~/.gitconfig